# Is there a way to RUN multiple versions of Node.js simultaneously on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm

So, to be clear, I'm not asking about the possibility of INSTALLING multiple versions of Node, or the capability of switching between multiple versions with something like nvm.

(The original nvm package for Mac/Linux has an "exec" command that lets you run a command under a particular version of node.  I think this would be a solution--but the nvm for Windows package doesn't have that "exec" command.)

Context:

I have an Azure function app API that must run under Node 14.0.0 (a requirement of Azure Function Core Tools version ~3, which itself is a customer requirement).

I also have a basic React app (using Parcel bundler) that runs under Node 11.14.0.  I can't update the Node version to 14.0.0 because of an error ("Cannot locate the bindings file...").

For testing purposes, I need to run both simultaneously, so I can hit my API with my React app.

I have tried starting my API under Node 14.0.0, then using nvm to switch to 11.14.0 to run the React app, but it causes the API to fail with an "unsupported Node version" error.  I haven't tried the converse approach because this error (along with the UAC prompt) tells me that the Node version in use is global.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to run two versions of Node on Windows?  Or can anyone suggest another practical work-around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Docker for that? I think your situation is really the reason why Docker exists.